# I want to delete all bin and obj folders to force all projects to rebuild everything

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, batch-file, cmd

I work with multiple projects, and I want to recursively delete all folders with the name 'bin' or 'obj' that way I am sure that all projects will rebuild everything (sometimes it's the only way to force Visual Studio to forget all about previous builds).

Is there a quick way to accomplish this (with a .bat file for example) without having to write a .NET program?

Comment: It would be nice if Build->Clean Solution actually did this.

Comment: There is a plugin I found called CleanBinAndObj which deletes all the bin and obj folders. Very effective for single solutions containing many projects.

Answer (score 708, accepted):

This depends on the shell you prefer to use.

If you are using the cmd shell on Windows then the following should work:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S bin') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%G"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S obj') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%G"
```

If you are using a bash or zsh type shell (such as git bash or babun on Windows or most Linux / OS X shells) then this is a much nicer, more succinct way to do what you want:

```
find . -iname "bin" | xargs rm -rf
find . -iname "obj" | xargs rm -rf
```

and this can be reduced to one line with an OR:

```
find . -iname "bin" -o -iname "obj" | xargs rm -rf
```

Note that if your directories of filenames contain spaces or quotes, find will send those entries as-is, which xargs may split into multiple entries. If your shell supports them, `-print0` and `-0` will work around this short-coming, so the above examples become:

```
find . -iname "bin" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
find . -iname "obj" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

and:

```
find . -iname "bin" -o -iname "obj" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

If you are using Powershell then you can use this:

```
Get-ChildItem .\ -include bin,obj -Recurse | foreach ($_) { remove-item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse }
```

as seen in [Robert H's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5924807/542251) - just make sure you give him credit for the powershell answer rather than me if you choose to up-vote anything :)

It would of course be wise to run whatever command you choose somewhere safe first to test it!

Comment: thx for your answer.
I get an error: %%G was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Hmm that's odd - it works fine on my machine (vista 64bit business) - I'll try it on an xp machine too.

Comment: allright i got it to work. one strange issue is that when there is a bin folder in the root he doesn't delete anything. but that doesn't matter

Comment: have you got any idea how i let the script search in a folder other than it's running from?

Comment: got it, by doing:
r:
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S obj') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%G"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S bin') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%G"
Pause

Comment: Note that iterating over `dir` output in this way can lead to unexpected failures with Unicode file or directory names and the console being set to Raster fonts. Characters that won't fit into the OEM codepage will be converted to their nearest equivalent or `?`. The most likely result is that whatever you're doing with the output it just cannot find the files. Note that this doesn't happen if you use `for` to iterate.

Comment: "%%G was unexpected at this time" - this happens when you run it from the command line instead from inside a batch file. Use single '%'s in this case.

Comment: +1 Would you mind to explain the code for me? Please.

Comment: @SteveWillcock It's better than clean. Clean won't remove dlls that are not referenced in the project anymore (leftovers).

Comment: Doesn't work in Windows 8. The powershell script below works.

Comment: We can use 'name' instead of 'iname' if you want to do the search case-sensitive. find . -name "bin" | xargs rm -rf

Comment: Make sure you don't have any programs open that have locked the files. Otherwise you might get strange access denied errors.

Comment: I would suggest excluding node_modules if you have it. A lot of packages have their own bin folder (like Gulp) and it can cause things to break if you delete them. You'll likely have to run `npm install` to repopulate the bin folder.

Comment: I had the some need as JED, I excluded the node_modules with this command. `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -include bin,obj | Where-Object {$_.FullName -notMatch "node_modules"}` After this you can pipe into the foreach as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I don't recommend those commands. I've tried it and it messed up my entire repository. Looks like it entered inside the .git folders and messed everything up

Comment: Doesn't work without second comment.

Comment: On Windows 11 only the powershell solution works.

Answer (score 501):

I found this thread and got bingo.  A little more searching turned up this power shell script:

```
Get-ChildItem .\ -include bin,obj -Recurse | ForEach-Object ($_) { Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force -Recurse }
```

Or more terse:

```
gci -include bin,obj -recurse | remove-item -force -recurse
```

I thought I'd share, considering that I did not find the answer when I was looking here.

Comment: @Nigel, Isn't this solution extremely un-performant? Why not write a custom C script that can run at 10x the speed?

Comment: I needed to also exclude folders from the searchpath, and I like the `-WhatIf` flag to test first, so I ended up with this: `$foldersToRemove='bin','obj';[string[]]$foldersToIgnore='ThirdParty';Get-ChildItem .\ -Include $foldersToRemove -Recurse|Where-Object{$_.FullName -inotmatch "\\$($foldersToIgnore -join '|')\\"}|Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -WhatIf` (a bit messy here as one line though :) )

Comment: @ChrisJ  Consider adding a new answer with your solution.

Comment: @JohnySkovdal same thing but smaller: `gci -exclude "*.dll" -include bin,obj -recurse | remove-item -force -recurse`

Answer (score 90):

This worked for me:

```
for /d /r . %%d in (bin,obj) do @if exist "%%d" rd /s/q "%%d"
```

Based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/201888/how-to-create-batch-file-that-delete-all-the-folders-named-bin-or-obj-recursi/201892#201892) on superuser.com

Comment: Great, and easy to extend. I use for /d /r . %%d in (bin,obj,App_Data,packages) do @if exist "%%d" rd /s/q "%%d"

Comment: @ParoX you need to run it inside a .bat file

Answer (score 43):

I wrote [a powershell script](https://github.com/doblak/ps-clean) to do it.

The advantage is that it prints out a summary of deleted folders, and ignored ones if you specified any subfolder hierarchy to be ignored.

[image: Output example]

Comment: +1 very nice! Just found out that we can actually debug and see the variables like a full-fetch debugger in Window Power Shell!

Comment: I like this solution. I don't have to mess with Visual Studio and I can run this when I want. Very nice!

Comment: Suits my needs perfectly, but I'm not sure why this couldn't be a gist rather than a full-blown repo. :-)

Comment: Nice work! I would omit all directories scanning because when you have thousands of subdirectories, this could be quite slow. Too high price just for statistics :-). Also I would add `$_ -notmatch 'node_modules'` condition to `$FoldersToRemove` variable definition

Comment: On top of what Tomino suggested, I suggest excluding the packages folder. Here's the updated list

$FoldersToRemove = Get-ChildItem .\ -include bin,obj -Recurse   | where {$_ -notmatch '_tools' -and $_ -notmatch '_build' -and $_ -notmatch 'node_modules' -and $_ -notmatch 'packages'} | foreach {$_.fullname}

Comment: Still a nice solution in 2022!

Answer (score 36):

I use to always add a new target on my solutions for achieving this.

```
<Target Name="clean_folders">
  <RemoveDir Directories=".\ProjectName\bin" />
  <RemoveDir Directories=".\ProjectName\obj" />
  <RemoveDir Directories="$(ProjectVarName)\bin" />
  <RemoveDir Directories="$(ProjectVarName)\obj" />
</Target>
```

And you can call it from command line

```
msbuild /t:clean_folders
```

This can be your batch file.

```
msbuild /t:clean_folders
PAUSE
```

Comment: This does not work for a sln file since you cannot call custom targets on them or do you know a workaround for this

Comment: @PiotrOwsiak yes, you need to create file "before.MySlnFileName.sln.targets" in the same directory where you have your .sln and put there your target definitions

Comment: you can add AfterTargets="Clean" as an attribute to the Target, it will be automatically called after the Clean which is invoked directly or indirectly when doing a rebuild

Answer (score 16):

Nothing worked for me. I needed to delete all files in bin and obj folders for debug and release. My solution:

1.Right click project, unload, right click again edit, go to bottom

2.Insert

```
<Target Name="DeleteBinObjFolders" BeforeTargets="Clean">
  <RemoveDir Directories="..\..\Publish" />
  <RemoveDir Directories=".\bin" />
  <RemoveDir Directories="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)" />
</Target>
```

3. Save, reload project, right click clean and presto.

Answer (score 13):

NB: This is an old answer and may need a tweak for newer versions as of VS 2019 and some obj artifacts. Before using this approach, please make sure VS doesn't need anything in your target and output directory to build successfully.

Something like that should do it in a pretty elegant way, after clean target:

```xml
<Target Name="RemoveObjAndBin" AfterTargets="Clean">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(TargetDir)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: In VS2019 i found out that this makes the IDE hang for quite some time and has issues with Rebuild and project.assets.json

Comment: Thanks Mattias, I have added a warning. I guess it depends on the project type and maybe not a good idea to fully clean some of the projects. There should be a tweak for that.

Answer (score 13):

A very quick and painless way is to use the `rimraf` npm utility, install it globally first:

```
> npm i rimraf -g
```

And then the command from your project root is quite simple (which can be saved to a script file):

```
projectRoot> rimraf **/bin **/obj
```

To optimize the desired effect you can leverage the project event targets (the one you could use is `BeforeRebuild` and make it run the previous command) which are specified in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-extend-the-visual-studio-build-process?view=vs-2017

I like the rimraf utility as it is crossplat and really quick. But, you can also use the `RemoveDir` command in the .csproj if you decide to go with the target event option. The `RemoveDir` approach was well explained in another answer here by @Shaman: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22306653/1534753

Comment: Work on Mac too!

Comment: Yes (almost?) NodeJS/npm works everywhere... hah.

Comment: IMHO, If your are working on a Unix like OS, such as Linux, macOS,  you actually don't need rimraf. `rm -rf **/bin **/obj` will do the same thing. However, one thing is worth reminding, if you have Projects that live on a deeper level subdirectory, both solutions will not delete the bin/obj dirs of those projects. So this solution works for most scenarios, but not all scenarios.

Answer (score 7):

To delete bin and obj before build add to project file:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <!-- Remove obj folder -->
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)" />
    <!-- Remove bin folder -->
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(BaseOutputPath)" />
</Target>
```

Here is article: [How to remove bin and/or obj folder before the build or deploy](http://kitsula.com/Article/How-to-remove-bin-obj-folder-before-build-deploy)

Comment: You'll only want to do this on a rebuild, though. Unless you want _every_ build to be a rebuild!

Answer (score 7):

Very similar to Steve's PowerShell scripts. I just added TestResults and packages to it as it is needed for most of the projects.

```
Get-ChildItem .\ -include bin,obj,packages,TestResults -Recurse | foreach ($_) { remove-item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse }
```

Answer (score 6):

This is my batch file that I use for deleting all BIN and OBJ folders recursively.

1. Create an empty file and name it *DeleteBinObjFolders.bat*
2. Copy-paste code the below code into the *DeleteBinObjFolders.bat*
3. Move the *DeleteBinObjFolders.bat* file in the same folder with your solution (*.sln) file.

```sh
@echo off
@echo Deleting all BIN and OBJ folders...
for /d /r . %%d in (bin,obj) do @if exist "%%d" rd /s/q "%%d"
@echo BIN and OBJ folders successfully deleted :) Close the window.
pause > nul
```

Comment: I just put this script on my desktop - but added the line `cd C:\Git\Workspace` after the first line...

Comment: Please note, that /r takes precedence over /d, therefore files named "bin" and "obj" might also be deleted. The FOR command has discrete "modes". R and D are examples of those modes, of which only one is active any give time.

Answer (score 6):

I use a slight modification of [Robert H](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5924807/6891713) which skips errors and prints the delete files. I usally also clear the `.vs`, `_resharper` and `package` folders:

```
Get-ChildItem -include bin,obj,packages,'_ReSharper.Caches','.vs' -Force -Recurse | foreach ($_) { remove-item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose}
```

Also worth to note is the `git` command which clears all changes inclusive ignored files and directories:

```
git clean -dfx
```

Comment: git clean -dfx is perfect

Comment: Mind you `git clean` will remove everything that is not part of root repo. May not be what you want if you need to remove only bin and obj.

Answer (score 4):

In `VS 2019/VS 2022` this is the only sane solution.

In the solution folder (where the `.sln` file is located), create a file called `Directory.Build.props` and add edit it as shown below. Read about this special file [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019).

### Directory.Build.props

```xml
<Project>
  <Target Name="RemoveObjAndBinFolders" AfterTargets="Clean">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ObjFolder>$(ProjectDir)$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)</ObjFolder>
      <BinFolder>$(ProjectDir)$(BaseOutputPath)</BinFolder>

      <!-- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web sets $(BaseIntermediateOutputPath) to -->
      <!-- an absolute path. Not fixed up to MsBuild 17! -->
      <BaseIntermediateOutputPathFix Condition="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath.StartsWith($(MSBuildProjectDirectory)))">$([MSBuild]::MakeRelative(
        $(ProjectDir),
        $(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)
      ))</BaseIntermediateOutputPathFix>
    
      <ObjFolder Condition="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath.StartsWith($(MSBuildProjectDirectory)))">$(ProjectDir)$(BaseIntermediateOutputPathFix)</ObjFolder>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ObjFiles Include="$(ObjFolder)/*.*"
                Exclude="$(ObjFolder)/project.assets.json" />
      <ObjSubFolders
                Include="$([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories('$(ObjFolder)'))" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <!-- Remove "obj" sub folders -->
    <RemoveDir Directories="@(ObjSubFolders)" ContinueOnError="true" />
    <!-- Remove "obj" files (keeping necessary asset file)-->
    <Delete Files="@(ObjFiles)" />
    
    <!-- Remove "bin" folders -->
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(BinFolder)" ContinueOnError="true" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

No need to modify a bunch of `.csproj` files. Also, note that I'm **not** removing `$(TargetDir)` as some have suggested. Doing so might cripple the build system if `$(OutDir)` has been set to some custom directory (a common thing to do).

Comment: It should be noted that this solution sometimes interferes with VS, causing it to complain about a missing `project.assets.json`. Have since deactivated it in my solution. Some improvements are necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Several solutions above give answers how to exclude folders, but not in cmd. Expanding on [Steve Willcock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/755433/10200388), to exclude e.g. the `node_modules` folder, that may have `bin` folders in it, one can use the expanded one-liner below.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S bin obj ^|find ^"node_modules^" /v /i') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%G"
```

As noted by others, in the case of putting the above command in a cmd script and not using it directly in the command line, substitute `%G` with `%%G`.

Comment: replace `%G` with `%%G`

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [CleanProject](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Clean%20Project%20Overview), it will delete bin folders, obj folders, TestResults folders and Resharper folders. The source code is also available.

Comment: The project appears to have moved to here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Clean-Cleans-Visual-Studio-a05bca4f

Answer (score 3):

from [Using Windows PowerShell to remove obj, bin and ReSharper folders](http://blog.smoura.com/using-windows-powershell-to-remove-obj-bin-and-resharper-folders/)

very similar to [Robert H answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5924807/184572) with shorter syntax

1. run powershell
2. **cd**(change dir) to root of your project folder
3. paste and run below script

   **dir .\ -include bin,obj,*resharper* -recurse | foreach($*) { rd $_.fullname –Recurse –Force}**

Answer (score 3):

[Here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12206011/25812) I gave to a similar question, Simple, easy, works pretty good and does not require anything else than what you already have with Visual Studio.

As others have responded already Clean will remove all artifacts that are generated by the build. But it will leave behind everything else.

If you have some customizations in your MSBuild project this could spell trouble and leave behind stuff you would think it should have deleted.

You can circumvent this problem with a simple change to your .*proj by adding this somewhere near the end :

```
<Target Name="SpicNSpan"
        AfterTargets="Clean">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(OUTDIR)"/>
</Target>
```

Which will remove everything in your bin folder of the current platform/configuration.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio, I've a nice custom command that I can run over a solution:

1. Create an external tool from Tools->External Tools like this:

[image: Visual Studio external tools dialog]

Command: cmd.exe

Arguments: /c "for /d /r . %d in (bin,obj) do @if exist "%d" rd /s/q "%d""

Initial directory: $(SolutionDir)

2. Add the command to the Solution context menu.

Right-click on the toolbar and select Customize button:

[image: Visual Studio Commands Customize Menu]

Add a new command and select the correct External Command (in my case was External Command 6 as it was the sixth command):

[image: Visual Studio Commands Dialog]

3. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

I actually hate obj files littering the source trees. I usually setup projects so that they output obj files outside source tree. For C# projects I usually use

```
 <IntermediateOutputPath>..\..\obj\$(AssemblyName)\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
```

For C++ projects

```
 IntermediateDirectory="..\..\obj\$(ProjectName)\$(ConfigurationName)"
```

Answer (score 1):

On our build server, we explicitly delete the bin and obj directories, via nant scripts.

Each project build script is responsible for it's output/temp directories. Works nicely that way. So when we change a project and add a new one, we base the script off a working script, and you notice the delete stage and take care of it.

If you doing it on you logic development machine, I'd stick to clean via Visual Studio as others have mentioned.

Comment: sometimes i just have to be sure that all builds are completely new. I can't trust clean solution for doing that.deleting bin and obj has often proven more reliable

Comment: For us, only builds from the 'build machine' are tested, or used in production, so the developers don't have must be 'all clean' type issues, and the build server does that. Also means no one developer is needed to make a full build.

Comment: What is the easiest way to do this with nant? I have A hierarchy of a couple dozen projects and I'd rather not misfire on a delete script. =)

Comment: We have many executables/dlls 'asset' built, so per asset we have a nant script that builds it. For each one there is a Delete section where we place a line for each debug/release bin/obj directory we want deleted.

Answer (score 1):

http://vsclean.codeplex.com/

> Command line tool that finds Visual
>   Studio solutions and runs the Clean
>   command on them. This lets you clean
>   up the /bin/* directories of all those
>   old projects you have lying around on
>   your harddrive

Answer (score 1):

You could actually take the PS suggestion a little further and create a vbs file in the project directory like this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim oShell, appCmd
Set oShell  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
appCmd      = "powershell -noexit Get-ChildItem .\ -include bin,obj -Recurse | foreach ($_) { remove-item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse -WhatIf }"
oShell.Run appCmd, 4, false
```

For safety, I have included -WhatIf parameter, so remove it if you are satisfied with the list on the first run.

Answer (score 0):

Is 'clean' not good enough?  Note that you can call msbuild with /t:clean from the command-line.

Comment: Indeed "clean" is not good enough. This is especially true when using MEF. "Clean Solution" does not get rid of references you've removed which can cause issues when dynamically loading a folder's DLLs.

Comment: A lot of "works on my machine" bugs are caused by old or unexpected stuff sitting around in the bin/obj folders that is not removed by doing a "clean".

Answer (score 0):

We have a large .SLN files with many project files.    I started the policy of having a "ViewLocal" directory where all non-sourcecontrolled files are located.   Inside that directory is an 'Inter' and an 'Out' directory.  For the intermediate files, and the output files, respectively.

This obviously makes it easy to just go to your 'viewlocal' directory and do a simple delete, to get rid of everything.

Before you spent time figuring out a way to work around this with scripts, you might think about setting up something similar.

I won't lie though, maintaining such a setup in a large organization has proved....interesting.   Especially when you use technologies such as QT that like to process files and create non-sourcecontrolled source files.  But that is a whole OTHER story!

Answer (score 0):

Considering the PS1 file is present in the currentFolder (the folder within which you need to delete bin and obj folders)

```
$currentPath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$currentFolder = Split-Path $currentPath

Get-ChildItem $currentFolder -include bin,obj -Recurse | foreach ($_) { remove-item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the solution in batch. I am using the following command:

`FOR /D /R %%G in (obj,bin) DO @IF EXIST %%G IF %%~aG geq d RMDIR /S /Q "%%G"`

---

The reason not using `DIR /S /AD /B xxx`
1. `DIR /S /AD /B obj` will return empty list (at least on my Windows10)
[image]
2. `DIR /S /AD /B *obj` will contain the result which is not expected (tobj folder)
[image]

Comment: ```@IF EXIST %%G IF %%~aG geq d``` is used for checking path existing and the path is a folder not a file.

Answer (score 0):

This Works Fine For Me:
start for /d /r . %%d in (bin,obj, ClientBin,Generated_Code) do @if exist "%%d" rd /s /q "%%d"

Answer (score 0):

I use .bat file with this commad to do that.

```
for /f %%F in ('dir /b /ad /s ^| findstr /iles "Bin"') do RMDIR /s /q "%%F"
for /f %%F in ('dir /b /ad /s ^| findstr /iles "Obj"') do RMDIR /s /q "%%F"
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach to this problem. Rather than write a script to hunt for all the "obj" and "bin" folders in various places, I direct the build process to group those folders in a single, convenient location.

Add a `Directory.Build.props` file to the solution folder like so:

```xml
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <BaseProjectArtifactPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory).artifacts\$(MSBuildProjectName)</BaseProjectArtifactPath>
        <BaseOutputPath>$(BaseProjectArtifactPath)\bin\</BaseOutputPath>
        <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(BaseProjectArtifactPath)\obj\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Now, all of the "bin" & "obj" folders will be created in a separate `.artifacts` folder in the solution root, rather than the various project folders. Ready to start with a clean slate? Just delete the `.artifacts` folder and you're good to go.

Answer (score -3):

I think you can right click to your solution/project and click "Clean" button.

*As far as I remember it was working like that. I don't have my VS.NET with me now so can't test it.*

Comment: That's correct, and by far the most simple and easiest of all the suggested solutions (assuming it's appropriate to the specific situation....)

Comment: Sorry, but this is simply not true. It does not delete the contents of /obj which are the root of the problem. At least this is the situation with VS 2013 update 3.

Comment: Just had the same problem with VS2013 update 4. 
(Note: VS2010 was doing fine)

Comment: See this answer (on this very same question) for a better explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18317221/374198