# Delete everything in a directory except for one hidden directory in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

What's the best way to delete the entire contents of a directory, except for one (hidden) child directory? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

```
<Target Name="DeleteMe">
   <ItemGroup>
      <DeleteMe
         Include="$(PathRoot)/FolderToDelete/**/*.*"
         Exclude="$(PathRoot)/FolderToDelete/DoNotDeleteThisHiddenFolder/**/*.*"
         />
   </ItemGroup>
   <Delete Files="@(DeleteMe)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: This leaves empty directories.

Comment: This worked for my case. Note: you can add multiple paths in the Include or Exclude by dividing them with semi colon `;`