# Rename wp8 project in vs2012

Tags: c#

i have created a wp8 project using visual studio 2012 . Now i want to change my project name. I tried it using solution explorer but after renaming it the projects is deployed but does not run in the emulator.

Comment: Change the source code according to the new name

Comment: Does this link help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043618/proper-way-to-rename-solution-and-directories-in-visual-studio