# One or more projects could not be loaded, but VS but doesn't say which

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, refactoring, solution, csproj

I have a fairly large solution with multiple subprojects (mostly C# with 1 or 2 C++ projects), each in its own folder. I renamed the folders and the project names, then proceeded to editing the solution file using the same process described here: [Proper way to rename solution (and directories) in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043618/proper-way-to-rename-solution-and-directories-in-visual-studio)

After doing this, I wanted to test if everything went right so I opened the solution file. VS2008 complains:

> One or more projects in the solution could not be loaded for the
>   following reason(s):
>
> The project file or web has been moved, renamed or is not on your
>   computer.
>
> **These projects will be labeled as unavailable in Solution Explorer. Expand the project node to show the reason the project could not be
>   loaded.**

So I tried doing exactly as the bolded text says. However, there aren't any unavailable projects in Solution Explorer. All the subprojects are there, and I don't see any warning or errors or missing references or anything. The solution also compiles perfectly fine and I can run the application just fine as well.

The issue is that error keeps popping up when I open the solution, and I'm trying to stop it from doing so, because it's eventually going to enter into source control.

Has anyone encountered this before? Is there something I might've missed?

Comment: Open the .sln file in a text editor, Notepad will do.  Compare the list of projects you see there with the projects shown in the solution explorer window.  Delete the extra one.

Comment: This really helped.. I seem to have found unloaded project, after noticing there's one missing. It was deep inside another folder in the solution explorer that I never used and assumed that had nothing worthwhile. Thanks.

Comment: "It was deep inside another folder in the solution explorer that I never used and assumed that had nothing worthwhile" <-- that statement scares me.

Comment: These things can happen when you need to work with a huge codebase that you're unfamiliar with and doesn't have a lot of useful documentation :P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I seem to have found unloaded project, after noticing there's one missing by manually counting and comparing it to the number of projects the solution explorer reported. It was deep inside another folder in the solution explorer that I never used and assumed that had nothing worthwhile.

Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 6):

There is one easiest work around, open the solution file in notepad and check the address of the sub-projects(exp "dtproj" extensions),if you have just changed the name of folder or solution file then see if its properly depicting it in solution file.
there are few solution to this problem which are more simple and less problematic but still i find it direct and easy if one can manage.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the Output window:

View->Output

There should be more information about projects that failed loading.

Comment: It's blank. Also, there's no option to show output from Visual Studio.