# Rename project name from windowsformapplication2

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I have created an application in C# (connecting to Teradata database)that I named it as windowsformapplication2 (the default that comes). But, now I want to change the name to a meaningful name(CPU_Scoring). I have tried to rename project and solution, but I see the components in 'bin' are the same. When I run my application, it runs as windowsformapplication2 not` CPU_Scoring. Is there was way to do this, or do I have to create my application again ?

Comment: You need to change the assembly name. Right click your project, go to properties. Click `Application` on the left, and then change 'Assembly Name' (and probably default namespace too).

Comment: Project > Properties.  Spend an half hour looking what is there, press F1 if you don't understand something.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio

- In Solution Explorer, right click on Main solution > Rename
- In Solution Explorer, right click on project (under solution) >
  Rename
- In Solution Explorer, double click, or right click on Properties >
  Application Tab, rename Assembly name and Default namespace to match.
- Also rename the namespace, Open one of your class files. Right click
  the namespace > Rename... this should search and replace all
  references to your namespace throughout the project.
- Close the project > rename the project folder.
- Edit .sln file in notepad, change the path to the cjproj. ie
  windowsformapplication2\bar.csproj --> CPU_Scoring\bar.csproj

You might also like to have a look on [Proper way to rename solution (and directories) in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8801822/3796048)