# Compile error after renaming projects in my solution

Tags: c#, wpf

I've refactored my solution, and after renaming my projects and compiling I've got following strange errors for a WPF Window.

Compile error in the xaml of the window:
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Diagnostics' does not exist in the namespace 'CustomAssembly.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

*//There is no Diagnostics in this namespace.*

Compile error for the g.cs of the window:

Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'CustomAssembly.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

*//There is no Windows in this namespace.*

Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Type' does not exist in the namespace 'CustomAssembly.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

*//There is no Type in this namespace.*

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'CompanyName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

*//There is no CompanyName namespace.*

Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Delegate' does not exist in the namespace 'CUstomAssembly.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

*//There is no Type in this namespace.*

Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'ComponentModel' does not exist in the namespace 'CUstomAssembly.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

*//There is no ComponentModel in this namespace.*

Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'CodeDom' does not exist in the namespace 'CustomAssembly.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

*//There is no CodeDom in this namespace.*

Error   CS0538  'Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector' in explicit interface declaration is not an interface  CustomAssembly.CustomProject

The strange thing is, in the g.cs file are references which doesn't exist anymore and which aren't referenced.

I've already serached through all project files if there are still some Reference issues. Also deleted bin and obj folder for whole solution. -> Rebuild -> Same problem.

It looks like Visual Studio mix up the System from Microsoft and the CustomAssembly.System.

Does anyone have experience with this issue?

Regards

Comment: Did you updated the Xaml files as well?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I did.

Comment: Did you check this?

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8801822/1133284

Comment: what did you rename and to what? Did you use Replace all feature without previewing the changes?

Comment: I've refactored project names, assembly names and default namespaces. After that I've adjusted namespaces for all projects and updated all XAML files. To make sure that I haven't forgot anything I've started the solution analysis which result in no errors left.

Comment: @Brutus: I didn't change directories (for now)