# Rename a Project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a Solution in Visual Studio 2017 and one of the Projects is an ASP.NET Web Forms application.
How can I rename the Project? 
I changed the name in the .sln file but within the IDE it is still showing the old name. The folder name matches the required name.

Comment: Possibly answered here (works for 2015 so I imagine it will work for 2017 too) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043618/proper-way-to-rename-solution-and-directories-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio Enterprise 2013, right click en Solution and search in contextual menu the option "Rename", there put you new solution name [solution rename](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODDgg.jpg)

Comment: This works in Visual Studio 2017, as well, but I still had to open the `.sln` file and edit the reference to the previous folder name because I changed the folder name that contains the project.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the response. 
I had already tried editing the .sln file but it made no difference.
I finally found the problem was in the applicationhost.config file. Once I edited that the new name appeared.