# References missing after renaming a Project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have renamed a VS Solution and Project as per the steps in [Proper way to rename solution (and directories) in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043618/proper-way-to-rename-solution-and-directories-in-visual-studio) However when I delete the Bin and OBJ folders all my references are gone. When I return the Bin folder references are back. I want to delete the BIN folder create DLLs a fresh.

Comment: Your .proj file most likely has references with paths to that bin folder or their hintpath points to it.

Comment: @rene You are right, I have just checked on Properties and they are pointing to Bin folder eg ..\<MyProject>\bin\DotNetOpenAuth.Core.dll . What would be the right path to point to and do I change the path manually for all?

Comment: I don't know what the right path is, you have access to the folders and files on your system, I don't. Normally you would add these references with nuget package manager: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetOpenAuth which would give you a packages.config and a packages folder for each package you added. The package manager handles the dependencies.