# VS 2017 doesn't recognize assembly name after renaming it in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, .net-assembly

I have 2 projects: Domain - library project and WebUI - Asp.Net project. WebUI depends on Domain.
I've tried to rename solution name of my project and now I'm getting this error in my browser, when I'm trying to start Asp.Net Application.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to
>   service this request.
>
> CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SolutionName' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Source File: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\7c2cf4c9\4c15470e\App_Web_default.cshtml.6373d792.ysrztpbf.0.cs
>
> Line 27: using SolutionName.Domain;

I renamed every single occurrence of OldSolutionName to SolutionName. I removed the bin directory. I also followed this [Proper way to rename solution (and directories) in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043618/proper-way-to-rename-solution-and-directories-in-visual-studio) . What should I do in this situation to repair my project?

**EDIT**
I have resolved the problem by changing SolutionName to NewSolutionName.
But still no idea what was the problem.

Comment: Have you deleted the temporary asp.net files?

Comment: Yes, I have deleted the temporary files in Temp directory.

Comment: have you right clicked your solution and clicked add > existing project and select the project from your directory?