# Xamarin iOS error: Can not resolve reference

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

If I set up a Xamarin.Forms Solution in VS 2013 and try to run the iOS Version, it fails because of the following error:

> Error  2   Can not resolve reference: /Users/Koray/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/WalkiOS/aae389efbebffd5cd3625dcf99aad02c/C:/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/Xamarin.iOS/v1.0/Facades/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll  Walk.iOS

The Xamarin Build Host for Visual Studio is set up and a few weeks ago it worked fine.
I can't find anything to fix the error.

Comment: i think its because it cant find the path of you reference. you may have to manually reference it again.

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary I tried it it does not work either. Same error...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution is to update Xamarin on both machines to the same version. It should work fine if you do this.

Comment: This solution helped me today, you saved me so much time! Thank you :)

Comment: hi..how can i check which version instaled in mac?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you include a library that's not part of Xamarin.iOS. For example, when you Alt-Enter with ReSharper and it auto-adds a reference it thinks will work, when actually, there's no iOS equivalent of it. This happened to me when I had ReSharper add System.Web. The error looked like System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper, but the actual error was a non-Mono/non-iOS library being referenced by my project. Unfortunately, the error message is effectively wrong. I hope that helps!

Ybrin's answer is also true. I came across this SO article looking for a different answer, and ended up figuring out this alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both the above for me have occurred in the past in different situations for sure. The latest problem occurred because I had residual bin and obj directories with libraries built under a different shared project in the solution. I have been switching back and forth between a Xamarin.ios and Microsoft.ios project. I used a tip from a different article to clear all the bin and obj folders:

```
find . -iname "bin" -o -iname "obj" | xargs rm -rf
```

[How to delete the bin and obj folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755382/i-want-to-delete-all-bin-and-obj-folders-to-force-all-projects-to-rebuild-everyt)