# Visual Studio 2017 Unexpected Character '

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

So I had 2 weird system crashes, shall I say restarts. I tried to troubleshoot but i could't find any problem. Soon after I went into VS 2017 to practice a bit and this occurs.

Error:

> C:\Users\Shaky\App Data\Local\Temp.NET Framework,Version=v 4 . 5 . 2
>   . Assembly Attributes.cs(1,1,1,1): error CS 1056: Unexpected character
>   '

Note that it doesn't say which character, it just says " ' ".

And this repeats over and over like 202 times.

I had to separate framework version numbers with space because it doesn't let me pass the file path due to bad grammar, I searched how to do it, didn't find, this is my first time posting i think.

And this repeats over and over like 202 times.

Comment: can you paste a screen capture of those lines with errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get an CS1056 Unexpected character '' on this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577120/why-do-i-get-an-cs1056-unexpected-character-on-this-code)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fuqfgf

Comment: @mjwills That helped, error is gone. Thank you very much kind sir.

Answer (score 39):

As per https://lautzofdotnet.wordpress.com/tag/unexpected-character/ you need to do the following:

> Browse to the file in question in the Appdata\temp folder and you’ll
>   see at at least the file in question (my case
>   .NETFramework,Version=4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs).  I also had a few
>   other similar files for different .NET versions.
>
> Just delete them out of the temp folder.  When you recompile, they
>   will get recreated, but I received no errors and all is working well.

Note: The file can usually be found in `C:\Users\\{userName}\AppData\Local\Temp`

Answer (score 1):

This will also fix the problem if anyone encounters it in Xamarin forms for Android, delete the respective file (Example:"MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs ") out of the temp folder