# VS Build fails to load

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I am trying to run an application in VS2015 ,which was running perfectly before a system restart but I am now constantly getting this error error [CS1056: Unexpected character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhPgJ.png) .Installed MSBuild 2015 tool but still getting the same error.Please help.

Comment: What file/lines are those errors pointing to and what does the code there look like? You have the 'Description' column set far too wide and it's leaving off some potentially helpful detail.

Comment: Its pointing to a "Dispose" class in the HOD.Designer.cs stating 'HOD.dispose(bool)': suitable method found to override

Comment: You can try to check if the file HOD.Designer.cs contains a character that is not visible but that the compiler is trying to interpret, and try to create a new blank app to check if still have this issue, if yes, try to clean the folder C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Temp. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577120/why-do-i-get-an-cs1056-unexpected-character-on-this-code

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?