# Why do I get an CS1056 - Unexpected character '' on this code

Tags: c#

I'm getting this unexpected character '' error on this code:

```
 _timer = new Timer(1000){ AutoReset = true };‬

 _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get an CS1056 Unexpected character '' on this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577120/why-do-i-get-an-cs1056-unexpected-character-on-this-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying the `;` character from the end of your line into [this ASCII value checker](http://asciivalue.com/index.php) you can see that there are 8 characters there in total. Seems like there are some non-rendered characters after the `;` (`&#8236;`, not sure what it could be or where this came from).
Just delete it and retype a normal `;` character. Make sure to delete everything between the `;` and the line break to get rid of all the invisible characters.