# VS2015 auto complete function not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, autocomplete, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I recently got a new computer but I chose to install VS2015 after reinstalling Unity. I previously used monodevelop but thought I'd give VS a go (partially because it became the default program when opening scripts through Unity and I can't seem to change that).

I am however having a few problems due to the intellisense/auto complete function not working. I've read through a lot of answers on here but nothing seems to help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of Visual Studio 2015? Code, Community, Pro or Enterprise?

Comment: Community, sorry I forgot about that bit of info. First time posting here/about coding in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to rebuild your solution files.

From your projects root folder, copy **Assets** and **Project Settings** ONLY over to a new directory. From here open up one of your scenes, Unity will import assets and build the scene.

Once open, go to **Edit** -> **Preferences** -> **External Tools** and make sure that **Visual Studio 2015** is selected as the **External Script Editor** and then go **Assets** -> **Sync MonoDevelop Project** (Ignore the name MonoDevelop!)

See if that works for you.

Failing that follow the guide here and note what version of Unity you are using as there are different steps for pre 5.2 [Getting Started with Visual Studio Tools for Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn940025.aspx)

And if that doesn't work, it's going to be a problem with your Visual Studio install. I've had this before even on a new install. So try a re-install as a last resort.

Comment: The first part of your answer worked for me. This will save so much frustration

Comment: The same problem, but I'm not using Unity. A complete clean and rebuild of the solution worked for me. When I want a full clean, of every compiled artifact, I use this solution, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755382/i-want-to-delete-all-bin-and-obj-folders-to-force-all-projects-to-rebuild-everyt#755433, which I have as a script file. I don't know whether it was essential to fixing this problem. I suspect not, but I need to mention it.