# Missing .Net reference compile error with NuGet "TargetFramework" ... how to fix?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, compiler-errors, nuget

I had not seen this before, but when opening a project that worked fine on a coworkers machine I saw this...

> error : Your project does not reference ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1"
>   framework. Add a reference to ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" in the
>   "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet
>   restore.

The project targeted .net 4.71 and it had NuGet references like

```
<package id="log4net" version="2.0.8" targetFramework="net471" />
```

This is using the packages.config version of NuGet references (not the newer project based NuGet references in VS 15.9)

Visual Studio Version: 15.9

What is the cause and how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the cause, but when I converted the NuGet packages.config to [package references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference) it resolved the issue.

Looks this this is the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52833741/your-project-does-not-reference-netframework-version-v4-6-2-framework-add-a/54559385#54559385).

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem. Deleting the \bin and \obj folder in the project folder resolved this issue.

Comment: We have two csproj, one for net core and one for net 471. We use different obj/bin folders to avoid this error.