# visual studio 2019 file in debug folder not in project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Let me start by saying "If I don't ask I will never know" YES I am a Novice coder
Perhaps most coders at our level are happy if the Sub or Function works
I started a VB.Net & SQLite project and decided to store the DB name in App.config as a key/value pair
So I added the System.Configuration reference and the key = dbName & value Notes.db
After some reading and consideration I abandoned the design
Ran Clean and Rebuild and unchecked System.Configuration reference
In my Debug Folder I still see the key dbName see Screen Shot

**My Question is Why is this still here and can I delete it ?**

OR just go on with life and take my OC medication
[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: You can delete the entire bin and obj folders whenever you want. They will be recreated as required at the next build.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Why is it not removed with Clean or Rebuild I guess experience is the teacher here Thanks

Comment: I believe the necessary files and directories are created, but nothing is deleted when rebuilding. Imagine having a `test.txt` file in your build folder for testing purposes and it being deleted every time you make changes to your code. It wouldn't be very practical. @jmcilhinney You should make an answer.

Comment: If you want to delete all bin and obj folders, you can refer to: [I want to delete all bin and obj folders to force all projects to rebuild everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755382/i-want-to-delete-all-bin-and-obj-folders-to-force-all-projects-to-rebuild-everyt)